# echo message replacing whitespaces with backslashes

Tags: php, html, sql

Why am I getting the error message No users with name \' or \'1\'=\'1! when I enter ' or '1'='1 inside of the input? I know that my program blocks the SQL injection attempt, but why does it replace the whitespaces with backslashes?
add_pregmatch.php

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

$firstname = '';
    $errors = array('firstname'=>'', 'email'=>'');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // check name
    if(empty($_POST['firstname'])){
        $errors['firstname'] = 'Enter a name! <br />';
    } else {
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $firstname)){
            $errors['firstname'] = 'Name can only be letters! <br />';
        }
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SCIENCE FAIR</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <section class ="container grey-text">
    <form class="white" action="addpreg_match.php" method="POST">
    <tr>
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"></td></br>
        <?php echo $errors['firstname']; ?>
    </tr>
        <div class="center">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </div>
    </form>

</section>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$firstname'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($queryResult > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<div>
                <p>".$row['name']."<p>
                <p>".$row['email']."<p>
                </div>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "No users with name $firstname!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Try `echo "No users with name  {$_POST['firstname']}!";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not replacing the whitespaces with backslashes. Backslashes actually cancel, or negate, special characters - in this case, your single quotes (`'`). When you called `mysqli_real_escape_string`, it inserts these backslashes to negate any single quotes within `$username`, which makes the query read them as quote literals, instead of closing the string.

Think of it this way: if it didn't have backslashes, your query would read as

```
WHERE name = '' OR '1'='1'
```

This is SQL injection, and so by calling the escape function, it essentially turns the query into

```
WHERE name = " ' OR '1' = '1 "
```

This way, the single quotes don't close out the original quotation mark and are simply read as the `'` character.

If you want to output the original name, you can either store it as a variable and then call it when you need it, or use `$_POST['firstname']`.